# How to see that Jenkins polled a Git repo

Tags: git, jenkins

I know getting jenkins to poll a git repo is not best practise but I have to do it now as I do not have access to the git server.

My understanding is the build job will only happen if there are any changes. So if you have configured to poll every 5 mins, the build will only happen if there is a change so you could be waiting an hour to see something.

I'd still like to have confidence that jenkins has polled the git server and just been told there are no changes.

Can I see this anywhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

In the Jenkins GUI, drill down into the particular project and look on the column on the left. Near the bottom of the column, there should be a `Git Polling Log`.   If you don't see that entry, chances are the polling isn't completely active on your configuration, so check the `Poll SCM` setting in your build settings.